# Unable to setup Stack Overflow for Teams App in Microsoft Teams

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

We've just signed up for Stack Overflow for Teams on the Basic plan.

I'm now trying to add the relevant Microsoft Teams App - which is allowed by our 365 Admin (me).

I'm at the point where I have a new App on the side of Teams and a robot prompting me to login, however when I do I'm taken to a browser page that simply states:

Microsoft Teams integration setup canceled
This Stack Overflow Team is not currently active. Please contact your admin.

I have the same message when I try to add a tab in a Team channel as well.

[image]

This browser page is logged in as my account on Stack Overflow for Teams - that's my icon in the top right!

We have had a trial set up before by someone else that has since expired. It may well be this that's causing the clash - if so, how could I get around this? The old Team appears to be unrecoverable.

Or, is it something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try now. Your MS Team was still connected to your old SO Team. I've cleared the connection so you should be all set.

Comment: Works perfectly - thank you!

Comment: @Juice are there instructions on how to clear this connection? I think I'm in the same boat.

Comment: @TaylorEarl It's a tool we have on our end. If you open a ticket at https://s.tk/support, we can take care of that for you.

Comment: Awesome. I'll do that. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: For anyone that sees this in the future, support was quickly able to help me and I was able to pair my Microsoft Team to my Stack Overflow Team.